# How to setup Connectivity between the web component and java app

Tags: java

I am confused about the approach for application that am writing. I have developed the application jar and will be distributing via java webstart.

Now i need to putup a website supporting my app.

doubts i have

1)Can i pass this username and  password to the jar that i will be launching?

2)Can the webcomponent calculate the time for which the app was launched.

Basically i need to understand how will the webcomponents and my java app interact with each other in terms of any data required to pass to the app and any info retreaving from the app and putting on the web.

Thanks
Krisp

I want to pass arguments like username to the JNLP and then want to pass it to the main class.

Is there any direct way to do so rather than use database?

since JNLP is just an xml file. I could not find a direct way to do so.

Can i anybody refer me some working code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database is probably your best bet for sharing data between both apps. Other options are web services, sockets, RMI, etc.. You will probably need to look into all, on the surface initially, to know what suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

As for the Calculation of the time in my java app i can use currentTimeMillis() to calculate the time for which my app is running.

But senarios like app getting crashed or forced termination of the app it will not get saved.

Any Hints for communication in terms of data between the web and Application jar?

Thanks

Krisp